# Implementing zoom using MonoGame and two-fingers gesture

Tags: c#, android, monogame

I want to implement zoom feature using two-fingers slide in/out gesture that is commonly met in games such as Angry Birds. Now i'm using slider zoom and it feels not so good as the simple gesture. So i've tried to look at the gestures implementation in MonoGame but haven't figured out what actualy can help me to achieve described beahviour.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you need to use the `TouchPanel` gesture functionality to detect the `Pinch` gesture, then process the resultant gestures.

---

The longer answer...

You will get multiple `GestureType.Pinch` gesture events per user gesture, followed by a `GestureType.PinchComplete` when the user releases one or both fingers.  Each `Pinch` event will have two pairs of vectors - a current position and a position change for each touch point.  To calculate the actual change for the pinch you need to back-calculate the prior positions of each touch point, get the distance between the touch points at prior and current states, then subtract to get the total change.  Compare this to the distance of the original pinch touch points (the original positions of the touch points from the first pinch event) to get a total distance difference.

First, make sure you initialize the `TouchPanel.EnabledGestures` property to include `GestureType.Pinch` and optionally `GestureType.PinchComplete` depending on whether you want to capture the end of the user's pinch gesture.

Next, use something similar to this (called from your `Game` class's `Update` method) to process the events

```
bool _pinching = false;
float _pinchInitialDistance;

private void HandleTouchInput() 
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.GetGesture();

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Pinch)
        {
            // current positions
            Vector2 a = gesture.Position;
            Vector2 b = gesture.Position2;
            float dist = Vector2.Distance(a, b);

            // prior positions
            Vector2 aOld = gesture.Position - gesture.Delta;
            Vector2 bOld = gesture.Position2 - gesture.Delta2;
            float distOld = Vector2.Distance(aOld, bOld);

            if (!_pinching)
            {
                // start of pinch, record original distance
                _pinching = true;
                _pinchInitialDistance = distOld;
            }

            // work out zoom amount based on pinch distance...
            float scale = (distOld - dist) * 0.05f;
            ZoomBy(scale);
        }
        else if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.PinchComplete)
        {
            // end of pinch
            _pinching = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The fun part is working out the zoom amounts.  There are two basic options:

1. As shown above, use a scaling factor to alter zoom based on the raw change in distance represented by the current `Pinch` event.  This is fairly simple and probably does what you need it to do.  In this case you can probably drop the `_pinching` and `_pinchInitialDistance` fields and related code.
2. Track the distance between the original touch points and set zoom based on current distance as a percentage of initial distance (`float zoom = dist / _pinchInitialDistance; ZoomTo(zoom);`)

Which one you choose depends on how you're handling zoom at the moment.

In either case, you might also want to record the central point between the touch points to use as the center of your zoom rather than pinning the zoom point to the center of the screen.  Or if you want to get ***really*** silly with it, record the original touch points (`aOld` and `bOld` from the first `Pinch` event) and do translation, rotation and scaling operations to have those two points follow the current touch points.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I've never actually used the Monogame libraries, so hopefully the code is functional for you.